# Classic ASP, Sending E-mail on windows server 2008 - error '8004020f'

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to send e-mail with classic ASP (I am stuck with an old app so I have to use classic ASP here) on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.

I guess lots of thing change from win server 2003 to 2008. I am using the following code but I am getting this error (BTW, error message is so "informative");

> error '8004020f'
>
> /poo.asp, line 32

Here is the code;

```
<!-- 
    METADATA 
    TYPE="typelib" 
    UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D"  
    NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Library" 
-->  
<%  

    'Declare variables 
    Dim sch, cdoConfig, cdoMessage
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")  

    With cdoConfig.Fields  
        .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  
        .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "mail.example.com"
        'Set SMTP port which is 25 by default 
        .Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 587 
        .Update  
    End With 

    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

    With cdoMessage 
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = "info@example.com" 
        .To = "me@example2.com" 
        .Subject = "Sample CDO Message" 
        .TextBody = "This is a test for CDO.message" 
        .Send 
    End With 

    Set cdoMessage = Nothing  
    Set cdoConfig = Nothing  

Response.write "<HTML><head><title>A message has been sent.</title></head><body>A message has been sent.</body></HTML>"

%>
```

Also, I just installed **Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1** from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1004 into my server but it didn't change anything.

**NOTE:** I could send e-mail over localhost if it works. doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might come across the following error:

> error '8004020f'  The event class for this subscription is in an
>
> invalid partition

This error message comes from cdosys.h, and has nothing to do with any sort of "partition" - it is actually lumped in with other errors in an overloaded message. The error code is actually attributed to the following:

```
CONST LONG CDO_E_RECIPIENTS_REJECTED = 0x8004020FL
```

Which means that the e-mail was rejected by the server for some reason. Here are some things you can try to alleviate the problem:

1. Make sure the SMTP server allows anonymous (non-authenticated) relaying. If your SMTP requires outgoing authentication, see [Article #2026](http://www.aspfaq.com/show.asp?id=2026#auth).
2. Check if the problem is specific to the domain name(s) used in the e-mail addresses of the recipients. For example, some users have complained that they can send to users on their own domain only; others have said that they can send to any domain except their own (see [Article #2511](http://www.aspfaq.com/show.asp?id=2511) for some potential causes and solutions).
3. It may be simply that the e-mail address is being rejected, but other configuration settings on the SMTP server are preventing the true error message from being relayed propely back to the ASP script ... so verify that the address is valid.
4. If you have a proxy or firewall, make sure the web server is set up to correctly pass through it, that the SMTP server knows about it, and that the proxy allows access to port 25.
5. Try using a SendUsing value of 1 (pickup) instead of 2 (port). E.g. the following line:

   ```
   .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
   ```

Becomes

```
.Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPickup
```

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/why-does-cdo-message-give-me-8004020f-errors.html

Comment: ok you just copy and paste the article which I have already read

Comment: I am sending e-mail using asp.net System.Net class easily on the same server. do u think I need to specify password and username?

Comment: The server you are trying to send the e-mail from is rejecting the e-mail recipients.  Try using localhost for the SMTP server if it worked outside of CDO.

Comment: Also why are you using port 587, if you use port 25 does it work?

Comment: In turkey, we need to use port 587. I am not sure why but network provider all over the turkey has changed from 25 to 587 a few years ago.

Comment: thanks Sean, changing it to localhost was the magic all along :)